# RestKit Core Data mapping connection with foreign key in the URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have an API with two endpoints:

**/projects**

```
{
  project_list:[{"project_id": 1, "project_name": "Ben"},
                {"project_id": 2, "project_name": "Jerry"}]
}
```

**/projects/1/members**

```
{
  member_list:[{"member_id": 1, "member_name": "Ben"},
               {"member_id": 2, "member_name": "Jerry"}]
}
```

A project has-many members and a member has-one project. I'm using RestKit 0.20.1 to map these to a Core Data store.

*Current code:*

```
// ###############################
// ## Configure Project mapping ##
// ###############################
RKEntityMapping *projectMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
projectMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"projectId" ];
[projectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"project_id": @"projectId",
                                                    @"project_name": @"projectName"}];

RKResponseDescriptor *projectDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:projectMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"project_list" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[ projectDescriptor ]];

// ##############################
// ## Configure Member mapping ##
// ##############################
RKEntityMapping *memberMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Member" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
memberMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"memberId" ];
[memberMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"member_id": @"memberId",
                                                   @"member_name": @"memberName"}];

RKResponseDescriptor *memberDescriptior = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:memberMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"member_list" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[ memberDescriptor ]];
```

The closest I've come are these examples: http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKConnectionDescription.html, but they depend on the foreign key being in the JSON response.

**How do I connect these when the project foreign key is in the URL and not returned in the JSON data when retrieving the members?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the foreign key as described in the reference you link, you just need to get it...

To get it, you need to use a path pattern and metadata mapping. You also want to use `RKRoute` as it does a lot of the work with path patterns.

Define your path pattern like:

```
projects/:identity/members
```

And then in your mapping you can define the foreign key to pick this up:

```
@"@metadata.routing.parameters.identity": @"foreignKey",
```

See the 'Metadata Mapping' section of the [RKObjectManager docs](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The foreignKey seems to be an attribute on my Member class. But I only have a Core Data object relationship property with a real Account object, not an accountId property. Do I need to create that and have redundant data on the Project object?

Comment: Yes, you need to create it. You should be able to make it transient so it won't actually be persisted into your DB.

Comment: Is it possible to have access to have a look to the final source code ?