# RestKit Dynamic Mapping from URL Identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm updating a old app. it was using restkit 0.9.x and now the app will use 0.24.0

i have a api who give language data.

sampleurl.com/api/v3/lang

```
{
"sites": [
    {
        "id": "de",
        "label": "Deutsch"
    },
    {
        "id": "fr",
        "label": "Français"
    },
    {
        "id": "en",
        "label": "English"
    }
]}
```

if i use sampleurl.com/api/v3/lang/fr , i get the info from the lang fr.
i have data, who are specific to a language.
i get the data with sampleurl.com/api/v3/lang/fr/data

i dont have the id of the language inside the json form data.
In our core data model, we have a entity language, and a entity Data, with a relation between them. it was working fine with the old RestKit, but i cant get it working with reskit 0.24.x

i can get all the data from Data, but when i try with the Relation, it does not work because the relation is not optional.

My old code that work with restkit 0.9.x:

```
[_objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:self.dataMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/lang/:langid/data"];
[self.dataMapping mapKeyPath:@"parentIdKey" toRelationship:@"data" withMapping:self.langMapping];
```

So my object Data has a object lang.

Does someone know how to do that mapping in RestKit 0.24.x

Comment: Show a pic of the data model, or describe the relationship and lang attribute name. Have you tried using a key path in the path (replacing :langid with something like :data.langid)?

Comment: I dont have enough rep to post a image.
i've one Entity language, with 2 property id and label as string, and one ToMany relation to data that is optional
a second Entity Data that have some property( data, id, detail, ...) and one toOne relation to language that is not optional.

Comment: And did you try changing :langid to something else? Like language.id?

Comment: yes, that doesn't work.
It seem that ma problem is similar to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734694/restkit-core-data-mapping-connection-with-foreign-key-in-the-url
i've added a transient attribute to data named langId, added 
       @"@metadata.routing.parameters.langid":@"langId" to my mapping dictionnary, and try to figure out how to have the data set with a route, but so far i didnt success to do it.

Comment: Basically you would need to explicitly add the value to the path string to have it available in the metadata to push into the data entity

Comment: Thanks, i finally got it working with your old topic answer.
    [_objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:@"lang" pathPattern:@"/lang/:id/data"  method:RKRequestMethodGET]]; and then 
addConnectionForRelationship:@"language" connectedBy:@{ @"langId": @"id" }];